# Android create list items from JSON multi-data field

Tags: android, json, listitem

How can I create ListItems from the following example JSON output?

```
[
  {
   "section": {
    "term": "Description#1",
    "tid": "10"
  }
  },
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {
   "section": {
    "term": "Description#2",
    "tid": "12"
  }
 }
]
```

The idea is to use the term data for each section as the label of a listItem. However, when the listitem is clicked it is the tid which is detected for the purpose fetching database results matching the passed tid.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but the primary issue is how to use the term as the listItem label but the tid as the data returned in the OnItemClickListener?

Answer (score 1):

**Launcher**

```
public class Launcher {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "[{" + 
            "   \"section\": {" + 
            "       \"term\": \"Description#1\"," + 
            "       \"tid\": \"10\"" + 
            "   }" + 
            "}," + 
            "{" + 
            "   " + 
            "}," + 
            "{" + 
            "   " + 
            "}," + 
            "{" + 
            "   " + 
            "}," + 
            "{" + 
            "   " + 
            "}," + 
            "{" + 
            "   " + 
            "}," + 
            "{" + 
            "   " + 
            "}," + 
            "{" + 
            "   " + 
            "}," + 
            "{" + 
            "   \"section\": {" + 
            "       \"term\": \"Description#2\"," + 
            "       \"tid\": \"12\"" + 
            "   }" + 
            "}]";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>(){}.getType();
    List<MyObject > objList = gson.fromJson(str, type);


    assert(objList != null);

    for(MyObject obj : objList){
      //..
    }
}

 }
```

**MyObject**

```
public class MyObject {
public Section section;   

   public Section getSection() {
    return section;
}  
}
```

**Section**

```
public class Section {
private String term;
private String tid;

public String getTerm() {
    return term;
}
public String getTid() {
    return tid;
}
}
```

Implement geters in loop

Comment: Thanks for this but how do I use both items of the json data in creating my listitems. I.E: use the term as the listItem label but the tid as the data returned in the OnItemClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

try this with through making an arraylist of hash map that contain the value and add that hash map in you array list

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just cast the JSON data to JSONObject's get the TID's and put them in an arraylist, set the terms in a list adapter and set an on click listener to return the tid from the position in the array list?